# 2-Column CSS List breaking when one side is bold

Tags: css, list, xhtml

This is something that I figure should be straightforward, but I can't seem to figure it out, and spending a couple of hours on a single list is driving me nuts.

What I'm trying to do is create a 2-column list, with "labels" on one side, and values on the other. I can get it to work if I leave font weights normal, or have both sides bold, but as soon as I make the labels bold and values normal, it staircases.

[A screenshot of it with bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyTUG.png)
[A screenshot without bold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dm8BL.png)

The applicable CSS:

```
ul.info {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul.info li.name {
    width: 150px;
    float: left;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ul.info li.value {
}
```

The HTML:

```
<ul class="info">
    <li class="name">Member Since</li>
    <li class="value"><?=$user->registerTime ?></li>

    <li class="name">Last Logged in</li>
    <li class="value"><?=($user_login !== null ? $user_login->login_time : 'Never') ?></li>

    <li class="name">Email verified?</li>
    <li class="value"><?=($user->emailVerified ? 'Yes' : 'No') ?></li>
</ul>
```

I've narrowed it down to the bold, but it doesn't make sense why that would break it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it will be down to the bold elements having extra vertical space being added somehow, which would explain why the floating isn't becoming staggered. Do you have a consistent `line-height` property applied to the list elements?

You'd be much better off using a definition list, rather than an unordered list. That way you can style `dt` and `dd` elements entirely separately, with the added advantage of your markup being much more semantic.

Comment: How did I forget about the `dl`, `dt`, `dd` tags? Used them instead (which, I'll agree are much more fitting) and it works perfectly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the height or min height of you LIs to a pixel figure greater than the height of the bolded font.

Answer (score 0):

What browser? It works fine for me in chrome.
I would suggest checking the script codes.. if they are generating valid xhtml.

[proof](http://jsfiddle.net/balron/KaamA/)

Comment: Ok, it seems like I am the only one who doesn't get any problems with that code provided.

Comment: Worked in that editor, but testing it on my site in FF, IE, Chrome, and Opera, it staircased in all of them. I would link to the site, but it's an internal link.

Comment: Ah :X Bad news.. I thought that editor can be trusted. Nevermind then :)